# Chapter 2 question 12 (a) Spivaks calculus

Tags: calculus, analysis

I’m working on this question, it asks: If $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational is $a + b$ necessarily irrational?

The answer says: Yes, if $(a + b)$ were rational, then $b = (a + b) - a$ would be rational.

My question is: Why are we allowed to assume that the product of $2$ rational numbers is a rational number?

Everything in Spivak's book seems to build upon previous knowledge, but it seems this part was left out.

Comment: You can easily prove sums and products of rational numbers are rational (and if I remember correctly, Spivak certainly makes you prove formulas for adding and multiplying fractions in chapter 1)

Comment: I suspect that if you look at where and how Spivak introduces the rational numbers you will find an assertion that sums and products of rationals are rational. That may be a formal claim, or one that relies on previous knowledge about the rules for adding and multiplying fractions. (I don't know how formal Spivak is at that level.)

Comment: You need to do some legwork. Just note that the product ${n_1 \over d_1} \cdot { n_2 \over d_2} = {n_1 n_2 \over d_1 d_2}$.

Comment: Spivak's answers uses a difference. Why are you asking about the product?